# QGIS Processing Algorithm populate alg.FIELD with attribute / field names

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

Using the new `@alg` decorator structure I am trying to populate a drop down with the fields (attributes in a table).

Using the code in https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#the-alg-decorator

I have

```
@alg(name='searchupdatealg', label='Search and update (alg)',
     group='mgm', group_label='Example scripts')
# 'INPUT' is the recommended name for the main input parameter
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name='INPUT', label='Input vector layer')
@alg.input(type=alg.FIELD, name='Attrib', label='Attribute')
# 'OUTPUT' is the recommended name for the main output parameter
```

Looking at older code as in http://www.qgistutorials.com/fi_FI/_images/8b.png

It looks like we have to get the fields and put them into the list -but how is this done when we have `@alg.input(type=alg.FIELD ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to put the fields into the parameter's combobox manually. Just add `parentLayerParameterName='INPUT'` to `@alg` decorator.

```
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name='INPUT', label='Input vector layer')
@alg.input(type=alg.FIELD, name='Attrib', label='Attribute',
           parentLayerParameterName='INPUT')
```

There is no explanation about this in [QGIS Processing Script Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html). But the parameter name comes from the constructor method of [`QgsProcessingParameterField`](https://api.qgis.org/api/3.4/classQgsProcessingParameterField.html#a332a026282c2fc5134b2dbbb10f28033).